# Under what circumstances can focus location be different from caret location?

Tags: c#

I am making a C# windows forms app with textboxes. The program needs very precise knowledge of when its form is activated and which textbox has input focus.   However I have discovered situations in which the caret is blinking in a textbox in my form and yet at the same time an icon on the desktop behind the window is selected. So if I press enter the selected icon on the desktop will be opened instead of giving me a new line on my textbox.  Clicking the  mouse on the textbox will fix the problem and give real focus to the textbox so I can interact with it.

It seems to happen most often when i have an internet browser window open and my app opens a form over the internet browser window.

I need to know what circumstances can cause this.  Could it be caused by the TopMost property of the form being a certain setting? Or WindowState? It is very hard to replicate so I haven't been able to find out through process of elimination changing the settings. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee that your window will be be the focused and foreground window after you open it, even though a specific textbox may be focused (within the context of your window).

In order to detect if your window is focused within the context of the OS, you're stuck with good old win32 API calls. `Form.ActiveForm`, or any other properties, are application specific (and wont tell you if your program is foreground on the OS)

```
//Check current foreground window
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "user32.dll" )]    
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

//Set current foreground window
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

An example of how to use these to enforce focus:

```
if(GetForegroundWindow() != yourForm.Handle)
{
    SetForegroundWindow(yourForm.Handle);
}
```

After you know that your application is the foreground window of the OS, `control.Focused` should work to determine what control within your window has focus.

**Edit**: I just wanted to add, that even if your window is `TopMost`, it does not mean that it will retain OS focus. It just means that it will be rendered on top of other windows that do not have this property set.